# Getting Fatal error: 'Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance'

Tags: php, zend-framework, database-connection, zend-db, zend-db-table

I want to get query from multi databases ,I'm trying to connection two databases (database1,database2)  I've define 
**application.ini**:

```
resources.multidb.db1.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.multidb.db1.params.host = 'localhost'
resources.multidb.db1.params.username = 'root'
resources.multidb.db1.params.password = ''
resources.multidb.db1.params.dbname = 'database1'
resources.multidb.db1.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.multidb.db2.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.multidb.db2.params.host = 'localhost'
resources.multidb.db2.params.username = 'root'
resources.multidb.db2.params.password = ''
resources.multidb.db2.params.dbname = 'database2'
```

I've added below code to **Bootstrap.php**:

```
protected function _initDbAdapter()
{           
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    $resource->init();

    $db1 = $resource->getDb('db1');
    $db2 = $resource->getDb('db2');

    Zend_Registry::set('db1', $db1);
    Zend_Registry::set('db2', $db2); 
}
```

and in Model .. I've define **File.php** for get query from db2 :

```
<?php
class Model_file extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'file';
    protected $_schema = 'db2';
}
```

and Model_Books for db1

```
 <?php
 class Model_Books extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    {
        protected $_name = 'subscriber';
        protected $_schema = 'db1';
    }
```

in controller I have this:

```
 $fileModel = new Model_file();
 $select = $fileModel->select();
 $booksModel = new Model_Books();
 $select = $booksModel->select();
```

but I'm getting this error:
***Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance'***

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508556/change-value-of-application-ini-parameters-in-zend-framework